# Преобразование строки в массив

Tags: php

Получаю из бд вот такое строчное значение:

```
'[0,11]'
```

Как теперь преобразовать его в массив php?

Comment: почему бы не получить сразу нормальное значение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если напрямую вламываясь, то:

```
$str = '[0,11]';
$result =  explode(',', trim($str, "]["));
```

**[trim](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php)** - обрежет скобки, т.к. вторым параметром  функция принимает список символов для удаления.

**[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)** - разобьет строку по разделителю "запятая" на массив чисел.

---

Еще вариант:

```
$str = '[0,11]';
$result =  json_decode($str);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d7d6b0b933dd591cee2faeb98ad6e88086ce8447

---

А правильнее, кмк, было бы сразу получать из БД правильный набор данных

Comment: Дополню что лучше для хранения массивов в бд лучше использовать функции serialize unserialize.