# Массив из списка PHP

Tags: php

У меня есть обычный текстовый список `$list = 'Яблоко,апельсин,малина,груша'`

Как из этого можно сделать массив `$list_array = ["Яблоко", "апельсин", "малина", "груша"]`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование строки в массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759741/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = 'Яблоко,апельсин,малина,груша';
$list_array = explode(',', $list);
```